# how can i use string interpolation based on condition in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I'm trying to display one of two options with string interpolation in my html file based on the condition in my typescript file, if the variable `cityName = ''` is an empty string then interpolate
`{{currentLocationCity.name}}` and if the variable `cityName = '!null'`
is not an empty string then interpolate `{{cityByCoordiantes.name}}`
, how can i achieve this, i can write two different divs for each result and use `*ngIf` to display one of them, but i think that there has to be a better way of achieving this.

Comment: Did you try using [Conditional Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) inside your template?

Comment: Instead of nesting div's for conditionally rendering, you can use <ng-container *ngIf=""></ng-container>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use anything like `div`, `ng-container`, even `ng-template` for else condition, but you can simply use ternary operator like this:

```html
<ng-container>
    {{ cityName ?  cityByCoordiantes.name : currentLocationCity.name}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thanks it was exactly what i was looking for